# What's the difference between "I am a racist" and "I am racist"?

Tags: word-usage, expression-choice

I often hear a lot of people say "he is a racist", but at the same time a lot of people say "he is racist" so what's the difference between the two?

Comment: One is a noun and the other is an adjective …

Comment: Same as the difference between "I am a beauty" and "I am beautiful". Or between "I am dangerous" and "I am a danger". Or between "I am cool" and "I am a fridge". It's just that the two different words *cool* and *fridge* look very different, but the two different words *racist* and *racist* don't look different at all.

Comment: "It is present' and 'it is a present', and 'he is patient' and 'he is a patient', have very different meanings, but noun-adjective homographs rarely give rise to such divergent meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, "He is a racist" implies that many of his actions and attitudes carry a racist flavor, while "He is racist" implies that in some cases he can have a racist attitude.

More generally, saying "What he did was racist" suggests only that the specific action referenced was of a racist nature.

But the distinctions can be subtle, and highly dependent on context.  Consider that virtually all of us have racist reactions to some situations, even though not nearly so many of us would be considered to be "a racist".

I will add that if an individual considers himself to be "a racist" that means that racism is a part of his identity, while if someone recognizes that some of his *thoughts* or *behaviors* are racist, that suggests that he may be seeking to rectify that condition.

Answer (score 1):

"She is [sage](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sage)" and "She is **a** sage"
the meanings are very similar, until someone points out that the former can also refer to an aromatic herb. Context is King, as they say.

*A sage* (noun) is a wise person, and a *sage person* (adjective) is someone who is wise.

1. **She is sage** / **she is racist**

We are describing the person's personality

2. **She is a sage** / **she is a racist**

We are *defining* that person.

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference between the noun and the adjective

1. He is a philanthropist (n.) -> The vast majority of his time is spent being actively involved in adding to the happiness and well-being of others. He is almost exclusively occupied with philanthropy.

The noun expresses a more permanent state

2. He is philanthropic (adj.) -> One of his attributes, among many attributes, is being actively involved in adding to the happiness and well-being of others. He is known to demonstrate aspects of philanthropy.

Compare:

He is a policeman (n.)

He is {like a policeman} (adjectival phrase)

He is 20 year old and an adult (n.)

Although he is only 12 years old, his attitude is very adult (adj.)